# Type {} is not assignable to type 'Notification[]' & Type is missing the following properties from type notification

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm very new to Typescript and I am making a fully functional instagram clone. Recently got the idea that for the notifications it  would be easier to have an array of objects with different properties to then render out. I imported the data from the json, however I am now getting this error.

**JSON DATA**

```
    {"username": "kahlilsassa ",
     "profileImage":
"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1587301092680941569/B2GsgnBg_400x400.jpg",
     "seen": true,
     "followed": true,
     "verified": false,
     "datePosted": "2022-11-01:11:09"


**Notification Component**
interface Props {
  notifications: Notification[] | null;
}

export interface Notification {
  requested: Array<requested> | null;
  username: string;
  profileImage: string;
  seen: boolean;
  followed: boolean;
  verified: boolean;
  datePosted: string;
}
}, 

**Home Component** 
 <Modal
 active={notifications}
 setActive={setNotifications}
 title="Notifications">
 <div className="divider">
 <Notifications notifications={data1} /> <----ERROR IS HERE
 </div>
 </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply says that the data you pass is an Object, you should pass array like this `notifications={[data1]}`

```js
**Home Component** 
 <Modal
 active={notifications}
 setActive={setNotifications}
 title="Notifications">
 <div className="divider">
 <Notifications notifications={[data1]} /> <----ERROR IS HERE
 </div>
 </Modal>
```

Comment: or simply remove the `[]` declaration in the Props to be `notifications: Notification[] | null;`